# How to avoid duplicate primary key in Entity Framework manual Insert?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Typically in the past before we used entity framework we used composite keys for every table and manually iterated the key. For a simple example, basically the parent tables in this case is vendor and log type, whose fk is the pk of the log table

```
+--------------+-------------+
| VendorID(PK) |    Name     |
+--------------+-------------+
|            1 | ABC Company |
|            2 | XYZ Company |
+--------------+-------------+

+---------------+---------------+------------+
| idVendor(PK ) | LogTypeID(PK) |    Name    |
+---------------+---------------+------------+
|             1 |             1 | Info       |
|             1 |             2 | Warning    |
|             1 |             3 | Error      |
|             2 |             1 | Notice     |
|             2 |             2 | Warning    |
|             2 |             3 | Alert      |
|             2 |             4 | Audit      |
|             2 |             5 | Restricted |
+---------------+---------------+------------+

    +--------------+---------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
    | idVendor(PK) | idLogType(PK) | LogID(PK) |               Message                |
    +--------------+---------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
    |            1 |             1 |         1 | Notice of event that happened        |
    |            1 |             1 |         2 | Another notice from a different user |
    |            1 |             3 |         1 | An error from an upload              |
    |            1 |             1 |         3 | Notice of user                       |
    |            1 |             3 |         2 | An error from delete                 |
    +--------------+---------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```

So basically in the stored procedure we would then just get the max id + 1 of the activity log where the vendor = abc company and log = info.  We prefer to use compound keys to enforce data consistency and we like to use the smallest data types possible instead of using arbitrary ints and big ints everywhere.  For instance the log type table i don't need to use a small int for the log type id because a vendor will never have more than 255 log types, so for every vendor we set up there custom log types and restart the logtypeid back to 1.

### Okay so now for the question..

Using entity framework when I manually iterate the LogID I sometimes get duplicate primary key errors on insert for QA (more activity for testing). We have a new AngularJS application that sends the insert request to us but when there are multiple inserts I guess the max function + 1 is happening immediately for all 3 inserts before any actual insert of the record. When this happens, it tries to insert the same LogID for the three inserts. How do I stop this from happening without compromising our database design thats been tried and true for years?

Here's sample code of the insert. I omitted unnecessary columns for the sake of keeping the question simple:

```
public IHttpActionResult InsertLog(JobOrderNote.InsertUpdate Log)
{
    using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
    {
        tbl_ActivityLog insLog = new tbl_ActivityLog()
        {
            LogEntry = Log.LogEntry,
            idVendor = Log.VendorID,
            idLogType = Log.LogTypeID,
            LogID = (db.tbl_ActivityLog
                            .Where(log =>
                                log.idVendor == log.VendorID &&
                                log.idLogType == log.LogTypeID)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty()
                            .Max(id => id == null ? 0 : id.LogID)) + 1,
        };

        db.tbl_ActivityLog.Add(insLog);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually generated IDs is considered a bad database practice.  It does not matter what tool set you are using.  Use database-generated auto-incrementing IDs.

If you must keep the table structure with the composite key as you have it, then I recommend creating a stored procedure that increments the ID numbers and returns a new one to you.  So you will need to create a table to manage the IDs.  So it will need to track the next ID number to use for the Message table, for each vendor and log type.  It will pre-increment the number, then return that number.  You will need to set the transaction isolation level to serializable so that two simultaneous calls to the stored procedure will result in unique values.

Comment: sighs - that sucks.  I thought it was going to be something like that  Right now for the past decade we've been using stored procedures so never encountered this limitation entity framework has.  From a database perspective only, it doesnt make sense to use an integer that has over 2 billion possibilities for data that only requires a byte (255) which is why we dont use auto incremeting keys.  I dont know if its bad practice because the constraints of the key dont allow duplicates so integrity is still there.  Maybe I'll play with some caching ideas temp hold data for iterations (idk).

Comment: This kind of thing can happen with stored procedures too, depending on the transaction isolation levels.  It's probably just less likely since it is happening in the DB.  It sounds like you are doing a lot of work to try and save a few bytes on those keys.  Consider benchmarking to see if that is truly necessary.

Comment: lol on the contrary I'm trying to save weeks possibly months worth of work.  The older system used this database without this duplicate pk errors (like you said, being inside the db it must have done process quicker so we never received the error). We're transitioning that system to an Angular\Web API application. So I'm trying to avoid redefining hundreds of tables lol.  Maybe I can just convert all the PKs into AKs with a powershell script and then put single column identity PKs in its place.  Should be an interesting project

Comment: i decided to use arbitrary auto-incrementing keys for the PK and move the composite key into an alternate key to maintain data integrity instead.  Thank you for your feedback Moby